# Error: [mobx-state-tree] expected mobx-state-tree type as argument 1, got undefined instead

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-state-tree

ERROR Error: [mobx-state-tree] expected mobx-state-tree type as argument 1, got undefined instead
ERROR Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

that happens when i created new model with its store and i was trying to declare it in the store root but i got this error ( i dont have any errors with my models code )

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when I tried to import model to another model from root `models/index.ts`. I'm using Ignite boilerplate, so all stores are automatically added to `models/index.ts`, when you import models from this file, there would be this error.

You should import models directly from their location (definition).

Details: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues/1582